# Android - Handling a grid

Tags: android, gridview, grid

I am trying to make a 2x2 grid of buttons and handle them. Right now I have a relative view activity with four buttons...but my question is: is the best way to do this? Than give each button a listener? Or is there anyway to add the buttons to the GridView and handle them all in one method? 
Ex.:
Instead of using something like
if(button1x1)...
if(button1x2)...
if(button2x2)...
if(button2x1)... 
and write a method for all of them, is there a way for me to just have one method and it will automatically detect which button is being pushed? Sorry if this is a confusing question, I can think it perfectly but translating to words is a bit difficult. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of you you can do

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {...
```

and then implement the `onClick` method as

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   switch(view.getId()){
   case R.id.A_UI_Element:
      //do what you need for this element
      break:
   case R.id.A_Different_UI_Element:
      //do what you need for this element
      break;
   //continue with cases for each element you want to be clickable
   }
}
```

Comment: Makes so much sense, did not even think about this. Now what if I want  one of them to lets say randomly light up, how would I do something like that? Would I need to write some sort of array? for one of the four to randomly light up?

Comment: completely different question.  Please accept this answer and create a new question.

Comment: I'm not asking how to set the colors and what not, I'm just wondering how I would go about doing something like that, but will do. Thanks for your help.