# Android - Randomly setting a button in a grid

Tags: android, gridview, grid

this is an extension to this question: [Android - Handling a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321996/android-handling-a-grid)
Basically, I am wondering how to make a grid of 4x4 buttons randomly change their features(text, color, etc.) I don't need help setting the actual change in text or color, I just need a way to go about something like this. I don't know if I should write an array and choose from there, or use the GridView. Just a little start to something is all I need, I'm not asking for lots of code. Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 4 ids are sequential as is

```
btnId1 = 8006;
btnId2 = 8007;
btnId3 = 8008;
btnId4 = 8009;

Random rn = new Random(); 
int chooseId = btnId1 + rn.nextInt(btnId4 - btnId1 + 1);
```

Comment: Right on! Thanks. This helped out more than you may think. Thanks for helping me user2310289, I really appreciate it. I will accept the answer in 5 minutes when I can. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number like so:

```
Random r=new Random();
r.nextInt(4);
```

this will give you a random number in the range [0,4).
Based on this random number, you change the properties of the appropriate tile/square which you can enumerate yourself from 0 to 3 since you have 4 tiles in total.

From both your questions it seems that you lack some basic programming knowledge of algorithms/approaches to problems. You should try to fill that gap, which will make you progress MUCH MUCH faster in your programming endeavors!

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I agree. I was thinking it would be a lot harder than it actually was, didn't even think of putting them in a sequential order and randomizing from there, I was thinking more along the lines of an array. But thank you for your input, I really appreciate it. Any constructive criticism from others helps.

Comment: This was not a criticism, it was a friendly suggestion that I think might help you speed up your learning by a great amount rather than stumbling on rather obvious things.